# Reference 'GetUnderlyingType' return from call to function 'GetUnderlyingType' may be null

Tags: c#, klocwork

I am getting below Klocwork issue, while doing code analysis,

**Reference 'GetUnderlyingType' return from call to function 'GetUnderlyingType' may be null**

```
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) != null)
                {
                    value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
                    objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString())), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("%", "");
                    objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(objProperty.PropertyType.ToString())), null);
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Type
>
> The type argument of the nullableType parameter, if the nullableType
>   parameter is a closed generic nullable type; **otherwise, null**

You handle this with your outer `if` clause, but VisualStudio doesn't seem to recognize it. The solution would be this:

```
var ut = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType);
if (ut != null)
{
    value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
    objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(ut.ToString())), null);
}
else
{
    value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("%", "");
    objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(objProperty.PropertyType.ToString())), null);
}
```

Comment: what code change required here, Could you please post code

Comment: I missed the outer if clause. The null is handeled, but that's not recognized by VS.